# Get the amount of unique ID's for which a variable is not completely NA

Tags: r, data.table

I want to figure out how many unique `NR` have all `C_P` values `NA`.

```
DT <- structure(list(NR = c(10001111, 10001111, 10001113, 10001114, 
10001115), C_P = c("8851", "NA", "8873", "NA", "NA"
),        B_LAND = c("NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

         NR  C_P B_LAND
1: 10001111 8851     NL
2: 10001111   NA     NL
3: 10001113 8873     NL
4: 10001114   NA     NL
5: 10001115   NA     NL
```

I am struggling to get the syntax right. I attempted;

```
DT[, .(uniqueNR_without_C_P = uniqueN(is.na(C_P)), by = NR]
```

The desired output is `2`, since there are two unique `NR`, for which there is no `C_P`.

Comment: Note there is no `NA` in your data. You defined it as the characther `"NA"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you could do:

```
DT[, all(is.na(C_P)), NR][, sum(V1)]
```

But since there no  `NA` value in your data but the characther `"NA"` you can do smth like:

```
is_string.NA = function(x) x == "NA"
DT[, all(is_string.NA(C_P)), NR][, sum(V1)]
```

Alternatively:

```
uniqueN(DT$NR)  - uniqueN(DT[!is_string.NA(C_P)]$NR)
```